# React componentDidMount not called

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Our UI designer designed a Tabs component in React. When you select a tab it selects a child to render based on index and only 1 child is rendered at once.

I want to invoke some function calls in child when the Tab becomes active. But componentDidMount is not called.

When the page is first loaded, the initial tabs componentDidMount gets called, but others wont. I guess its because they dont get rendered. But now when i switch to the other tab, it gets rendered but componentDidMount is not called.

So eventhoguh componentDidMount is defined, it never gets called, unless its the initial open tab. How can i make so that switching tabs also invokes the componentDidMount code?

```
<Tabs><Tab><MyTable/></Tab><Tab><MyTable2/></Tab></Tabs>
```

MyTable2 has componentDidMount that invokes data loading. But the componentDidMount is never invoked.

Tabs element just renders its children

```
<div>this.props.children[index]<div/>
```

And Tab element does same

```
<div>this.props.children<div/>
```

Comment: SOlved it by adding key parameter to the element. That way react change detection does everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use componentDidUpdate if you want to do something after props/state changed.

Comment: Props and state dont change